# I can't remember how I made this graph and I have to recreate it for other variables.

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I am pretty sure I created this graph while working with mixed effects model. I probably used a equation that looks something like this

weight ~ diet * time + (time | subject).

Does this graph look familiar to someone? What is the package or function used to create this graph? I tried looking into my R history but ran into a wall. Help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image: This is the image]

Comment: Colors aside, it looks like a `lattice`-based plot: https://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/trellis.html (sorry, not very specific)

Comment: I think it is `effects::Effect` .

Comment: @tmfmnk thanks! I got it!